# A or an? Which article must be used here?

Tags: articles

I am not sure which article I should use before the abbreviation NLSM, which stands for Non-Linear Sigma Model.

Example:

> It has a NLSM description.

or

> It has an NLSM description.

Answer (score 0):

I think **An** will be used here because the abbreviation gives the sound of **AN**LSM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).